# How do I Reverse this CSS3 Vertical Dropdown Animation?

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm designing a vertical dropdown header that opens and closes (using an input check type) when clicked and I can't get this opening animation to reverse for the closing animation because the closing animation is just a scaling trick and not the same as the opening animation.

This is my project: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLmbXd?editors=1100

I want to change this closing scaling animation to the actual animation:

```
@keyframes hideAnimation {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.5);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.5);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.5);
    transform: scaleY(0.5);
  }
  60% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0.25);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0.25);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.25);
    transform: scaleY(0.25);
  }
  80% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
  }
}
```

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is that max-height will animate and ease (in and out) based on your 9999px height, so it is going really fast to reach that distance.  Rather you need to use actual heights or set `max-height: 165px` on line 49 of your pen.

You could also simplify your css to this;

```css
.dropdown {position: relative;}
.dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transition: transform 0s ease-out 0.6s,max-height 0.6s ease-out;
}

.dropdown > .dropdown-menu li a {
  display: block;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  background: #EEE;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 white inset, 0 -1px 0 #d5d5d5 inset;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
.dropdown > .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
.dropdown > input[type="checkbox"] {
  opacity: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropdown > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 160px;
  display: block;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-out,max-height 0.6s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title">Dropdown Menu</h1>
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">First Menu</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Second Menu</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Third Menu</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe you should look at just using height or max-height for your transitions.  By using `overflow: hidden;` it effectively covers and hides the child elements.  By setting your `transition` in the 'checked' state it will use that transition, and when you 'uncheck' or close, it will use the unchecked transition.  All I did was add a delay to the `transform: scale(0);` so it does that after it is 'hidden'

Comment: I see. Is there a reason why the dropdown closes faster than it opens when I apply the non-scaling effect to both closing and opening the drop-down?  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xLmbXd?editors=0100

Comment: when it opens to a `max-height` of 900px it effectively stops at the height of it's children, thus following the speed of your `transform: scale()`.  When you close it, it is animating from a size of 900px to 0px in 2s.  that moves fast.